# How to order results by sum of a hasMany related table column in a laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to order my API results by the sum of a hasMany relationship column in a laravel app. I'm trying to order my results by the sum of the count column in plays table so songs with the most plays appear first. I've seen other SO answers but they mainly deal with count and not sum. My setup is

Tables

Songs

```
id
name
```

Plays

```
date
count
song_id
```

Models

Song.php

```
public function plays()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Play');
}
```

Play.php

```
public function song()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Song');
}
```

Contoller.php

```
// Works
// $songs = Song::withSum('plays', 'count')->paginate(10);

// Does not work with orderBy.
$songs = Song::withSum('plays', 'count')->orderBy('plays_sum_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

If I remove the orderBy from the above piece of code in the controller I get an array of songs with the plays_sum_count value set correctly but when I try to order it the request keeps running(in postman) resulting in an eventual timeout.

How can I get a result set ordered by the sum of the count column in plays?

Answer (score 0):

try group your result then order them by the sum:

```
$songs = Song::join('plays','plays.soung_id','=','songs.id')->select('songs.*')->groupBy('songs.*')
->orderByRaw('SUM(plays) DESC')>paginate(10);
```

please pay attention to the table names